# How to write opengl ES 2.0/3.0 in Common Lisp?

Tags: opengl-es, common-lisp

I'm want write one code that works in android and linux, so I think that I should start with cl-opengl, but the android uses opengl ES, so I think that I should use opengl ES 2.0 or 3.0, but I'm confusing with all this, I'm using sdl2 for create window and cl-opengl, but how to use opengl ES in common lisp? I must write two code one in opengl ES for Android and other code in opengl for Linux? Or I can write one code in opengl ES that work in both platforms? How to write opengl ES with cl-opengl? I'm almost lost.

And I think build to Android by ECL.

I try today again, and I follow the tutorial below:

https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_com_OpenGL/Modern_OpenGL_Introduction

I can draw the triangle with my code in C. But when I try with cl-opengl not:

```
(unless (gl::features-present-p (>= :glsl-version 1.2))
  (format t "Not support glsl 120.~%")
  (finish-output))
(let ((buffers (gl:gen-buffers 2))
      (vertex-buffer nil)
      (arr (gl:alloc-gl-array :float 6))
      (verts #(0.0 0.8
           -0.8 -0.8
           0.8 -0.8))
      (vs (gl:create-shader :vertex-shader))
      (fs (gl:create-shader :fragment-shader))
      (program nil)
      (attribute-coord2d nil))
  (setf vertex-buffer (elt buffers 0))
  (gl:bind-buffer :array-buffer vertex-buffer)
  (dotimes (i (length verts))
    (setf (gl:glaref arr i) (aref verts i)))
  (gl:buffer-data :array-buffer :static-draw arr)
  (gl:free-gl-array arr)
  (gl:shader-source vs *vertex-shader*)
  (gl:compile-shader vs)
  (gl:shader-source fs *fragment-shader*)
  (gl:compile-shader fs)
  (setf program (gl:create-program))
  (gl:attach-shader program vs)
  (gl:attach-shader program fs)
  (gl:link-program program)
  (setf attribute-coord2d (gl:get-attrib-location program "coord2d"))
  (gl:color 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0)
  (gl:clear :color-buffer-bit)
  (gl:use-program program)
  (gl:enable-vertex-attrib-array attribute-coord2d)
  (gl:vertex-attrib-pointer attribute-coord2d
                2
                :float
                :false
                0
                vertex-buffer)
  (gl:draw-arrays vertex-buffer 0 3)
  (gl:disable-vertex-attrib-array attribute-coord2d)
  (gl:delete-program program))
```

With the code above I get:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GL_INVALID_ENUM` probably means you passed the wrong constant somewhere, and it says this happened in `DRAW-ARRAYS`. I haven't used cl-opengl or Common Lisp before, but [glDrawArrays' first parameter should be the type of primitive](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) (both in GL and GL ES), e.g. `GL_TRIANGLES`. If cl-opengl is a 1:1 mapping to the GL API, then I assume your `(gl:draw-arrays vertex-buffer 0 3)` line is wrong, and should be something more like `(gl:draw-arrays gl:triangles 0 3)`?

Also `(gl:vertex-attrib-pointer attribute-coord2d 2 :float :false 0 vertex-buffer)` is suspicious to me. I think that last parameter should be 0. It's notionally a pointer, but in modern OpenGL and OpenGL ES (when you're using an array buffer like you are) it's actually an offset into the buffer.

Comment: You are right, is `(gl:draw-arrays :triangles 0 3)`. But now I have only black screen, I can't see the triangle.

Comment: Am I use of `attribute-coord2d` correctly? Its one int only, is it right?

Comment: I think that's right, but `gl:vertex-attrib-pointer attribute-coord2d 2 :float :false 0 vertex-buffer)` is suspicious to me. I think that last parameter should be `0`, it's notionally a pointer, but in modern OpenGL and OpenGL ES (when you're using an array buffer) it's actually an offset into the buffer.

Comment: You say "both in GL and GL ES", I, m confusing yet, in the code above I use GL ES, I'm right? Because I already see examples of codes with "include" of "GL ES" as was one lib different, but I understand that opengl ES is in the opengl lib, and is just one "pattern" of which functions will use. I'm right?

Comment: OpenGL ES is a different API to OpenGL, strictly speaking: the version numbers are different, there are different sets of functions available. However, for the most part it is like it is just a subset of OpenGL.

Comment: You are right again, the last parameter should be `(cffi:null-pointer)`, now I see the blue triangle in the screen.

Comment: But does being a subset mean that I don't need to add anything besides opengl lib? or do i also need to add "opengl ES" header for example? I'm too confused about that, because I've seen examples with such a header being added. Am I use opengl or opengl ES in my code above?

Comment: If you're running on a normal Linux desktop it is presumably standard OpenGL. The header and library names for ES might be different, I am not sure. If you are careful it is possible to write code that will work fine on both OpenGL and OpenGL ES. I need to do other things right now and you will have to research it yourself, but I have done it before. One thing in particular you may need to do is request GL ES when creating the OpenGL context on devices that have ES.

Comment: When you can add about `gl: vertex-attrib-pointer` to your answer so I can mark it as correct.